# Selecting more than one feature from raster attribute table using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, sql

How do I select more than one features from raster attribute table?

For example:

```
"lc_2001" = 21, 22, 23, 24 AND "lc_2006" = 11, 31, 41, 51
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it's SQL, you can use `IN` and select from a list, thus:

```sql
"lc_2001" IN (21, 22, 23, 24) AND "lc_2006" IN (11, 31, 41, 51)
```